# How can I initialize a python threaded socketserver with another class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a python irc bot, and I would like to add a tcp server so the bot can echo messages sent to it in irc channels. I am using the python socketserver module so that it supports both linux and freebsd (I use both). I have a short testing script here:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import socketserver
from threading import Thread


class announce():
    """ Return message uppercase """
    def uppercase(message):
        print (message.upper())

class ThreadedTCPRequestHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    """ Echo data back in uppercase """
    def handle(self):
        self.announce = announce
        data = str(self.request.recv(1024), 'utf-8')
        if data is not None:
            self.announce.uppercase(data)
            self.request.send(bytes("message recieved", 'utf-8'))
        self.request.close()

class ThreadedTCPServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn,     socketserver.TCPServer):
    daemon_threads = True
    allow_reuse_address = True

    def __init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass):
        socketserver.TCPServer.__init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST = "localhost"
    PORT = 2000
    server = ThreadedTCPServer((HOST, PORT), ThreadedTCPRequestHandler)
    try:
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        server.shutdown()
        server.server_close()
```

What I want to be able todo is have the irc bot start the tcp server, and have the tcp server send any data it receives to the bot.

The full (non-working) bot code is here: https://github.com/meskarune/autobot/blob/master/src/autobot.py

Below is a truncated version with the relevant pieces:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class AutoBot(irc.bot.SingleServerIRCBot):
    """Create the single server irc bot"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        self.config.read("autobot.conf")

        self.nick = self.config.get("irc", "nick")
        self.nickpass = self.config.get("irc", "nickpass")
        self.name = self.config.get("irc", "name")
        self.network = self.config.get("irc", "network")
        self.port = int(self.config.get("irc", "port"))
        self._ssl = self.config.getboolean("irc", "ssl")
        self.channel_list = [channel.strip() for channel in self.config.get("irc", "channels").split(",")]
        self.prefix = self.config.get("bot", "prefix")

        if self._ssl:
            factory = irc.connection.Factory(wrapper=ssl.wrap_socket)
        else:
            factory = irc.connectionFactory()
        try:
            irc.bot.SingleServerIRCBot.__init__(self, [(self.network, self.port)],
                                                self.nick, self.name,
                                                reconnection_interval=120,
                                                connect_factory = factory)
        except irc.client.ServerConnectionError:
            sys.stderr.write(sys.exc_info()[1])

        #Listen for data to announce to channels
        self.listenhost = self.config.get("tcp", "host")
        self.listenport = int(self.config.get("tcp", "port"))
        TCPinput(self.connection, self, self.listenhost, self.listenport)

    def announce(self, connection, text):
        """Send notice to joined channels"""
        for channel in self.channel_list:
            self.connection.notice(channel, text)
            self.log_message(channel, "-!-", "(notice) {0}: {1}"
                             .format(self.connection.get_nickname(), text))
class TCPinput():
    """Listen for data on a port and send it to Autobot.announce"""
    def __init__(self, connection, AutoBot, listenhost, listenport):
         self.connection = connection
         self.AutoBot = AutoBot
         self.listenhost = listenhost
         self.listenport = listenport
         server = ThreadedTCPServer((self.listenhost, self.listenport), ThreadedTCPRequestHandler)
         try:
             server.serve_forever()
         except:
             server.shutdown()
             server.server_close()
    def send(self, message):
        self.AutoBot.announce(self.connection, message.strip())

class ThreadedTCPRequestHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    """ Echo data back in uppercase """
    def handle(self):
        self.TCPinput = TCPinput
        data = str(self.request.recv(1024), 'utf-8')
        if data is not None:
            self.TCPinput.send(data.strip())
        self.request.close()

class ThreadedTCPServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, socketserver.TCPServer):
    daemon_threads = True
    allow_reuse_address = True

    def __init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass):
        socketserver.TCPServer.__init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass)

def main():
    bot = AutoBot()
    bot.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

With the current code the bot hangs upon running and when I do ctrl-c it connects and then crashes. I'd really love to know how I can get this working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `TCPinput`, you are calling `serve_forever` within the main thread of control, causing it to block. Instead, you need to run the server within a separate thread. You can achieve this by deriving `TCPinput` from `threading.Thread`, setting `serve_forever` as the thread target when initializing the object. Then, while initializing the bot, you can `Thread.start()` that thread.